# Post Json android in raw type

Tags: android, json

I'm new on android programming. I want to ask about how to post json on android native. This is the sample of json what i want to post.

```
{
    "user_id":"88880005",
    "keyword":"13828538",
    "items":["99999999999999999996","99999999999999999997"]
}
```

This what I have done.

```
private void save() {
    String URL = URL_Manager.URL_ScanIn;
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put("user_id", id);
    map.put("keyword", keyword);
    map.put("items", databarcode);

    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    try {
        aQuery.progress(progressDialog).ajax(URL, map, String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void callback(String url, String object, AjaxStatus status) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(object);
                    String result = jsonObject.getString("success");
                    String message= jsonObject.getString("message");
                    Log.d("tag", jsonObject.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
             }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) { Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
    }
}
```

In that sample I use postman in raw not form data. What should I do to post that data from my android.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps in Android. Add dependency in your gradle

```
 compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

call your webservice using below code

```
     String[] items= new String[]{"99999999999","9999997456"};
        JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
        object.put("user_id",user_id);
        object.put("keyword",keyword);
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(items));
            object.put("items",jsonArray);

        }catch (Exception e){}
        String yourData = object.toString();
        StringEntity entity = null;
        try {
            entity = new StringEntity(yourData);
            entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        } catch(Exception e) {
//Exception
        }

        String url="Your url here";

        new AsyncHttpClient().post(null,url,entity,"application/json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                try {
                    String object= new String(responseBody);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(object);
                    String result = jsonObject.getString("success");
                    String message= jsonObject.getString("message");
                    Log.d("tag", jsonObject.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: am i just change my method code with that code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code of HTTP POST with JSON request. Use this inside AsyncTask or Background thread.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;


public String executePost() {

    String requestJSON = "your json";
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {
        String myurl = "put your serverURL"
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(NetworkHelper.NetworkConnectTimeOut);
        conn.setReadTimeout(12000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(requestJSON);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        conn.connect();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        boolean responseStatus = false;
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            responseStatus = true;
        }

        inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
        if (inputStream != null && responseStatus) {
            result = readStream(inputStream);
            status = getJSONResponseStatus(result);
        } else {
            result = "Did not work!";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    Log.d("result****", result);
    return result;
}
```